# Handling errors in scala ZIO

Tags: scala, error-handling, zio

I wanted to handle some exceptions in ZIO using catchAll or catchSome as the below :

```
object Test extends App {

  def run(args: List[String]) =
    myApp.fold(_ => 1, _ => 0)

 val myApp =
    for {
      _ <- putStrLn(unsafeRun(toINT("3")).toString)
    } yield ()

def toINT(s: String): IO[IOException, Int]= {
     IO.succeed(s.toInt).map(v => v).catchAll(er =>IO.fail(er))
  }
```

the code succeeded in case I passed a valid format number but it's unable to   handle the exception in case I passed invalid format and idea ??

Comment: Why the `unsafeRun` in the middle of your IO? I think you want `for { i <- toINT("3"); _ <- putStrLn(i.toString)} yield ()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s.toInt` gets evaluated outside of the `IO` monad. What happens is that you evaluate `s.toInt` first and try to pass the result of that to `IO.succeed`, but an exception has already been thrown before you can pass anything to `IO.succeed`. The name of `succeed` already basically says that you are sure that whatever you pass it is a plain value that cannot fail.

The docs suggest using `Task.effect`, `IO.effect`, or `ZIO.effect` for lifting an effect that can fail into `ZIO`.

Comment: I got it but you can't do map or catch without wrapping the result in a monad so now the question is what is the best wrapper to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a program that worked for me:

```
val program =
  for {
    int <- toINT("3xyz")
    _ <- putStrLn(int.toString)
  } yield ()

def toINT(s: String): Task[Int] = {
  ZIO.fromTry(Try(s.toInt))
}

rt.unsafeRun(program.catchAll(t => putStrLn(t.getMessage)))
```

Comment: You can simplify you `toInt` with: ```def toINT(s: String): Task[Int] = {
  Task.effect(s.toInt))
}```. In `ZIO`, `effect` means "import that code which can fail (you can use `Task.effect` for throwable, or `ZIO.effect` for generic error management. See that for more generic answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63712633/what-is-zio-error-channel-and-how-to-get-a-feeling-about-what-to-put-in-it/63712634#63712634)