# What is ZIO error channel and how to get a feeling about what to put in it?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, io-monad, zio, bifunctor

`ZIO` (https://zio.dev/) is a scala framework which has at its core the `ZIO[R, E, A]` datastructure and its site gives the following information for the three parameters:

> **ZIO**
>
> The `ZIO[R, E, A]` data type has three type parameters:
>
> - **`R` - Environment Type**. The effect requires an environment of type `R`. If this type parameter is `Any`, it means the effect has no
>   requirements, because you can run the effect with any value (for
>   example, the unit value `()`).
> - **`E` - Failure Type**. The effect may fail with a value of type `E`. Some applications will use `Throwable`. If this type parameter is
>   `Nothing`, it means the effect cannot fail, because there are no
>   values of type Nothing.
> - **`A` - Success Type**. The effect may succeed with a value of type `A`. If this type parameter is `Unit`, it means the effect produces no
>   useful information, while if it is `Nothing`, it means the effect runs
>   forever (or until failure).

It's easy to get what `A` is: it's the value returned by the function in the nominal case, ie why we coded the function for.
`R` is so kind of dependency injection - an interesting topic, but we can just ignore it to use `ZIO` by alway setting it to `Any` (and there is actually a `IO[E, A] = ZIO[Any, E, A]` alias in the lib).

So, it remains the `E` type, which is for error (the famous error channel). I roughtly get that `IO[E, A]` is kind of `Either[E, A]`, but deals with effect (which is great).

My question is: why should I use an error channel EVERYWHERE in my application, and how can I decide what should go in the error channel?

Answer (score 7):

**1/ Why effect management with an error channel?**

As a developper, one of your hardest task is to decide what is an error and what is not in your application - or more preciselly, to discover failure modes: what the nominal path (ie the goal of that code), what is an expected error that can be dealt with by the application in some way later on, and what are unexpected errors that the application can't deal with. There is no definitive answer for that question, it depends of the application and context, and so it's you, the developper, who needs to decide.

But the hardest task is to build an application that keeps its promises (your promises, since you chose what is an error and what is the nominal path) and that is not surprising so that users, administrators, and dev - including the futur you in two weeks - know what the code do in most cases without having to guess and have *agency* to adapt to that behavior, including to respond to errors.

This is hard, and you need a *systematic* process to deals with all the possible cases without going made.

The error channel in `IO` bi-monad (and thus `ZIO`) helps you for that task: the `IO` monad helps you keep track of effects, which are the source of most errors, and the error channel makes explicit what are the possible error cases, and so other parts of the application have agency to deal with them if they can. **You will be able to manage your effects in a pure, consistant, composable way with explicit failure modes**.
Moreover, in the case of `ZIO`, you can easely import non-pure code like legacy java extremelly easily:

```
val pure = ZIO.effect(someJavaCodeThrowingException)
```

**2/ How do I choose what is an error?**

So, the error channel provide a way to encode answer to `what if?` question to futur dev working on that code. "What if database is down?" "there's a `DatabaseConnectionError`".
But all `what if` are not alike for YOUR use case, for CURRENT application level. "What if user is not found?"  - ah, it may be a totally expected answer at the low, "repository" level (like a "find" that didn't find anything), or it can be an error at an other level (like when you are in the process of authenticating an user, it should really be there). On the first case, you will likely not use the error channel: it's the nominal path, sometimes you don't find things. And in the second case, you will likelly use the error channel (`UserNotFoundError`).

So as we said, errors in error channel are typically for `what if` question that you may want to deal with in the application, just not at that function level. The first example of `DatabaseConnectionError` may be catch higher in the app and lead to an user message like "please try again" and a notification email to sysadmin ("quick, get a look, something if wrong here"). The `UserNotFoundError` will likely be managed as an error message for the user in the login form, something like "bad login or password, try again or recover credentials with that process".

So these cases (nominal and expected errors) are the easy parts. But there are some `what if` questions that your application, whatever the level, has no clue how to answer. *"What if I get a memory exception when I try to allocate that object?"* I don't have any clue, and actually, even if I had a clue, that's out of the scope of the things that I want to deal with for that application. So these errors DON'T go in the error channel. We call them failure and we crash the application when they happens, because it's likely that the application is now in an unknow, dangerous, zombie state.

Again, that choice (nominal path/error channel/failure) is your choice: two applications can make different choices. For example, a one-time-data-processing-app-then-discard-it will likelly treat all non-nominal paths as failures. There is a dev to catch the case in realtime and decide if it's important (see: Shell, Python, and any scripting where that strategy is heavely used - ok, sometimes even when there is no dev to catch errors:). On the other end of the specter, Nasa dev put EVERYTHING in the error channel(+), even memory CORRUPTION. Because it is an expected error, so the application need to know how to deal with that and continue.

(+)NOTE: AFAIK they don't use zio (for now), but the decision process about what is an error is the same, even in C.

To go further, I (@fanf42) gave a talk at [Scala.io](https://scala.io) conference. The talk, "Ssytematic error management in application", is available in *French* [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0PlcgR5M1Q). Yes, French, I know - but slides are available in *English* [here](https://speakerdeck.com/fanf42/systematic-error-management-we-ported-rudder-to-zio)! And you can ping me (see contact info near the end of slide deck).